# Detrending data standard deviations

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, data-analysis, time-series

I was doing some calculations in MATLAB, and noticed a pattern that may be obvious to stats experts, but I didn't notice it before.

If I have a time-series, and I remove a linear trend / detrend it, I find that the mean of the detrended data is zero, as expected.

However, I was surprised to find out that the standard deviation of both the detrended data and original data is roughly the same. Is this what one should expect?

Thanks!

Comment: Variance is translation invariant, so detrending (perhaps by differencing) shouldn't affect the variance in a big way.

Comment: Hi @SeanRoberson. Thanks, that is very helpful now.

Comment: It depends on how you measure standard deviation: if it is the *root-mean-square* difference from the mean of the data set, then you would expect detrending to make a possibly substantial difference; if it is the *rms* difference from the prediction of the linear regression, then you would expect detrending to make no difference